# Confusion on Domain Redirection

Tags: .net, vue.js, .net-core, dns

I have one dedicated IIS server on which .Net application is hosted. And another is Vue.js front-end which is hosted on another server. IIS server is having static IP and it is bonded with https://www.example.co.in and Front-End application is mapped with https://www.example.net Now I wanted to redirect the plain request which is coming to https://www.example.co.in without any further path should redirected to https://www.example.net and that can be done from DNS server by Domain redirecting. But the question is, when any further path with URL like https://www.example.co.in/.client/fullsync, will this also redirect to https://www.example.net?